# Android PushNotifications with PushPlugin on emulator

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin, ngcordova

I've been following [this sample](https://github.com/hollyschinsky/PushNotificationSample) to get android pushNotifications (with GCM) working on an android emulator.
After `$cordovaPush.register(config)` I get Ok as response. But it never runs my callback [`$scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived'`].
And in consequence I never get my registration ID.

I've created a google API project. And I'm using that project Id in the config.senderID when calling `$cordovaPush.register(config)`.

I've also registered a gmail account into my emulator.

I guess I have 2 questions.

1.Is it possible to get (and register) push notifications on an android emulator?

2. why don't I get a $cordovaPush:notificationReceived event that calls my callback?

   app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaPush, $cordovaDialogs, $cordovaMedia, $cordovaToast, ionPlatform, $http) {
           $scope.notifications = [];

   ```
   // call to register automatically upon device ready
   ionPlatform.ready.then(function (device) {
       $scope.register();
   });


   // Register
   $scope.register = function () {
       var config = null;

       if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
           config = {
               "senderID": "12834957xxxx" 
           };
       }

       $cordovaPush.register(config).then(function (result) {
           console.log("Register success " + result);

           $cordovaToast.showShortCenter('Registered for push notifications');
           $scope.registerDisabled=true;

       }, function (err) {
           console.log("Register error " + err)
       });
   }


   $scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify([notification]));
       if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
           handleAndroid(notification);
       }

   });

   // Android Notification Received Handler
   function handleAndroid(notification) {
       // ** NOTE: ** You could add code for when app is in foreground or not, or coming from coldstart here too
       //             via the console fields as shown.
       console.log("In foreground " + notification.foreground  + " Coldstart " + notification.coldstart);
       if (notification.event == "registered") {
           $scope.regId = notification.regid;
           storeDeviceToken("android");
       }
       else if (notification.event == "message") {
           $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.message, "Push Notification Received");
           $scope.$apply(function () {
               $scope.notifications.push(JSON.stringify(notification.message));
           })
       }
       else if (notification.event == "error")
           $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.msg, "Push notification error event");
       else $cordovaDialogs.alert(notification.event, "Push notification handler - Unprocessed Event");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. It has been reported in ngCordova github, but no replies yet.

I managed to fix it. I know it's not a good solution if you are using angular but it's the only way I'm able to catch the register Id.

1. Inside the config object you must specify the `'ecb'`:

   ```
   var androidConfig = {
       "senderID": "388573974286",
       "ecb": "function_to_be_called"
   };
   ```
2. Put outside the controller the function:

```
        window.function_to_be_called = function (notification) {
        switch(notification.event) {

            case 'registered':
                if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
                    alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
                }
                break;

            case 'message':
                // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
                break;

            case 'error':
                alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
                break;

            default:
                alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                break;
        }
    };
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, it works fine with everything inside the controller but it stop working when I move the implementation to a .factory. Your solution worked putting the function `window.function_to_be_called` inside the factory. I don't understand why that works but `$scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification)` does not.

Answer (score 4):

The fix is a lot simpler than it seems.
I changed from:

```
$scope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
```

to:

```
$scope.$on('pushNotificationReceived', function (event, notification) {
```

while [debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) I noticed this on ng-cordova.js:

```
angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.push', [])
    .factory('$cordovaPush', ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function ($q, $window, $rootScope) {
        return {
            onNotification: function (notification) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('pushNotificationReceived', notification);
                });
            },
```

That means that it's doing a broadcast for 'pushNotificationReceived'. Not 'notificationReceived' as [documented](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/).

Comment: also in my case to follow the http://devgirl.org/2014/12/16/push-notifications-sample-app-with-ionic-and-ngcordova/ tutorial in android I needed to commented this line $scope.$apply(function () { into handleAndroid function

Comment: It's so annoying that they left that part out in the documentation and still haven't fixed this simple line, the process of activating the push notifications is frustrating by itself without it... Thanks for the answer! You saved the day. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you update the event name as you said, I also have another problem, which says: `processmessage failed: message: jjavascript:angular.element(document.queryselector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('$cordovapush').onnotification({"event":"registered"`...

It happens when angular doesn't find 'ng-app' and it returns 'undefined' `angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'))`

So to solve this, you can set manually your '`ecb`' like this:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification
```

Thanks to this [ionic forum entry](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-push-cordovapush-is-undefined-for-get-method/17432/9)

Comment: do you have the latest version of cordovaPush? [2.4.0]

Answer (score 0):

please update your ng-cordova.js in lib/ng-cordova.js from http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ in ng-cordova-master\dist\ng-cordova.js